# pipe string to bash command in a function

Tags: string, bash, function, vim, pipe

I have a string (as a result of another function, but for now let's store it in `s` for sake of simplicity) and I want to *write* it *out*, through a pipe to a `bash` command. (It has to be a pipe, the command does not accept this kind of input as an argument.)

So the question is, how should I invoke `mycommand`, that is, what goes to `...`?

```vim
function! MyFunc()
    let s = "my string"
    execute ... !mycommand --flag
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via here string:

```vim
:let s = "my string"
:set shell=/bin/bash
:exe "!cat <<< " . shellescape(s)
```

*Output*

```
my string
```

Via pipe:

```vim
:exe "!echo " . shellescape(s) . " | cat "
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for! Why would you prefer `<<<` over `echo` + `|`?

Comment: @PeterVaro, well, here string is shorter, no need for `echo`, or `printf`. I'm not sure, but I think here string doesn't fork child processes as opposed to pipe. But the pipe is portable.

Comment: Interesting: if I map `:call MyFunc()` to a key, where `MyFunc` can have either the here-string or the pipe, both will require me to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> as many times as many newlines are in the string.. any idea on this one?

Comment: @PeterVaro, [can't reproduce](https://gist.github.com/98d3f016980cb71f110a08131d72acac)

Comment: One reason `<<<` is preferred over `echo` is that some versions of `echo` will interpret escape sequences (e.g. `\n`) in the string (while other versions won't) and some will try to treat part of the string as options if it starts with "-" (while others won't). Basically, it's not very predictable or portable for some strings. If you really want portability and predictability, use `"printf '%s\n' " . shellescape(s)`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov well, I can provide you my entire thing, it is not that long, [here we go](https://gist.github.com/petervaro/b516e092057da738afcb604fb27e652c)! (Thanks for the extra effort btw!)

Comment: @PeterVaro, you shouldn't pass the data as format string for `printf`. The first argument should be something like `'%s\n'`: `execute "!printf '\\%s\\n' " . shellescape(s)`. But it's probably not the root of the issue. I'll try to debug it later.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I updated the gist, thanks for the feedback, and unfortunately you were right, it is not the source of the problem! Cheers for degugging!

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov sorry for the late response! thanks for the try anyway, it is kind of working, but I'm just curious about the changes that you've added: instead of `silent! execute '...'` you added `execute 'silent ...'` and you also added the `<nowait>` argument -- why?

Comment: @PeterVaro, `silent !command` disables possible messages from the command. `silent! exe "!command"` seems to have the same effect. `<nowait>` is optional; it disables waiting for possible mappings starting with the defined `p` (`px`, `pxy`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```
:execute "!\"".s."\" | mycommand"
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I think @RuslanOsmanov is right about using the `shellescape` built-in function on `s` -- it makes the execution of the concatanated string safe!

Comment: @PeterVaro: Thank you for for the insight. I come here mostly to learn. Wanted to take a stab at this too.